# Prove the direct sum $U \oplus \ker f$ is isomorph to $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum, vector-space-isomorphism

I'm having trouble proving the following:

Let $V$, $U$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces and $f$ the surjective linear map from $V$ to $U$. I am required to prove the direct sum of $U+\ker f$ is isomorph to $V$.

I have gone about it the following way. Since the map is surjective $\dim f(V)=\dim U$, and thus $\dim V = \dim U + \dim\ker f$.

Firstly, How can I prove the sum $\ker f + U$ to be direct if it is not given that $f = f^2$ which is the only way I can prove that the intersection between $\ker f$ and $U$ is the zero vector. And secondly, when the dimensions of the direct sum and $V$ are the same, how would that support my proof?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $U$ and $\ker f$ are not subspaces of the same space so they cannot intersect. You probably wish to show $U \oplus \ker f \cong V$, where $U \oplus \ker f$ is the space $U \times \ker f$ with component-wise operations. Once you establish that $\dim (U \oplus \ker f) = \dim U + \dim\ker f = \dim V$, the proof is finished.

Comment: @mechanodroid there is no restriction that states W is not a subspace of V, so therefore we can’t surmise that ker f and W are not subspaces of the same space. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What I meant is that $U$ and $\ker f$ don't have to be subspaces of the same space.  Then $U + \ker f$ and $U \cap \ker f$ are not defined. $U \oplus \ker f$ is what you need. The definition of $U \oplus \ker f$ is the same even if $U, \ker f$ are both subspaces of some space $X$ and $U \cap \ker f \ne \{0\}$. $U \times \{0\}$ and $\{0\} \times \ker f$ are subspaces of $U \oplus \ker f$ such that $(U \times \{0\}) \dot+(\{0\} \times \ker f) = U \oplus \ker f$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ such that $\ker(f)\oplus V'=V$. Then $f|_W$ is an isomorphism from $W$ onto $U$:

- $\ker f|_W\subset \ker(f)\cap W=\{0\}$ and therefore $f|_W$ is injective;
- if $u\in U$, then there is a $v\in \ker f$ and a $w\in W$ such that $u=f(v+w)$. Therefore, since $v\in\ker f$, $u=f(w)$ and so $f|_W$ is injective.

So, we can define an isomorphism $\psi\colon U\oplus\ker f\longrightarrow V$ by $\psi(u+v)={f|_W}^{-1}(u)+v$ ($u\in U$ and $v\in\ker f$).